# AngularJS unit test directly in browser with Jasmine but without Karma or nodejs or any test runners

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

We can test normal JavaScript code in the browser using only Jasmine (by only I mean without Karma or any other test runners or nodejs).

Can we do this for AngularJS projects as well? If yes, how?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  At first I thought you were asking how to run Jasmine in the browser, but it would seem you know how to do that.  So what would be different about Angular code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. It's exactly the same like with plain js. You just need to use the methods for angular testing.

Take a look at this post:
http://dennis-nerush.blogspot.co.il/2015/08/creating-masked-input-directive-with.html

Comment: Thanks Dennis. After posting this question, I found the answer at Angularjs.org itself. https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing